How to calculate the percentage based on 2 numbers in the same row using Power BI DAX?
I have a table that looks like this.

I need to add one more column in Power BI to tell me the percentage of apples taken for each class. So that I can plot a percentage line on the graph.
How can I write a DAX formula to add in that column in Power BI?


you can try to create a column
Column = 'Table'[Number of apples taken]/'Table'[Number of apples issued]



I found my answer after playing around for a while.
Open a new measure on the visualization page and type in this.
% of apples taken by class = DIVIDE(sum('testing apples'[Number of apples taken]),SUM('testing apples'[Number of apples issued]))

